# Changing variables inside a csh script

Tags: bash, csh

I have a csh script and I have to callenter code here bash script that changes the value of an environment variable, like this:

`changevar` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export FFF=0
```

`beforevar.csh` file

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv FFF 1
echo "BEFORE: " $FFF
./changevar
echo "AFTER: " $FFF
```

Result:

```
BEFORE:  1
AFTER:  1
```

How do I change the `FFF` variable after, by calling the `changevar` script?

Thank you